# How to get WAR file deployed online?

Tags: hosting, war, vps

This might sound like a stupid question, but I have searched about it and couldn't find a clear answer, so I'm asking it here.

How do I get the WAR file online so I can access it from anywhere? I have a REST server in a war and I want to use it in an Android app so I need access to it from anywhere. Do I need a VPS? Can I host a VPS myself? I have searched about it but for some reason I can't find a clear instruction on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is what you need to do.

First of all, you will have to download and run a web server on your computer. I use tomcat6 or tomcat7. On Linux, "sudo apt-get install tomcat7". Then, "service tomcat7 start" in order to start the server, and "service tomcat7 stop" the server.

On your router (that faces the internet), you will have to port forward (not safe!) all the traffic from 8080 or 80 (whatever port your rest server is at), to go to the computer that is hosting the rest server. For a typical Linksys router, that means you have to log on to 192.168.1.1, and adjust the port settings. So, get the local IP address of your computer (usually IPV4), and forward all the traffic on port 8080 (on the external facing router) to go to this local IP address.

Now, copy the war to the webserver (for tomcat7, /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps.)  Before you copy the war to this directory, be sure to COMPLETELY remove any old .war applications or folders with the same name.

Then, restart the server. You should be able to access the server using the external IP address of your router as the IP address. The external IP address will be listed on your router's homepage. Your external IP address will change over time-- if you want a static IP address, it would probably be best to find a commercial host or to purchase a static IP address from your ISP.

Comment: I did what you said, when I go to http://www.canyouseeme.org/ and enter my port it says the service is there but when I try to reach it through my browser (http://[wan ip]:8080/[servicename]) I can not find the default index.html page ( I get a 404 message) . When I go to localhost:8080/[servicename] it shows the web page successfully.

By the way, I am using Jetty and not Tomcat.

Comment: Are you sure you are forwarding it to the correct local IP address? Can you host and hit a regular web server?

Comment: Apparently my router configuration page reserves port 8080. I am sure the local IP is correct. Still can't get it to work

Comment: Hmm. What do you mean by "reserves"?

Comment: My router configuration page is on 192.168.1.1:8080

Comment: Ohhh, have you tried hosting the rest server on a different port?

Comment: Yes, I configured it like this:
http://oi40.tinypic.com/2n8sic.jpg

But still can't access the page that is in my war externally. When I deploy it locally it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. The only thing you can try is to maybe have jetty listen on a different port? I don't know, sorry.